# 50 puntos de reputacion para comentar, ¿es realmente necesario?

Tags: discusión, comentarios, privilegios

Me inscribi en esta pagina hace poquito y queria decir que no entiendo la finalidad de pedir 50 puntos antes de poder comentar una pregunta o una respuesta (o un mismo comentario).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primero que nada, uno puede realizar preguntas y respuestas de forma inmediata sin la necesidad de tener siquiera 5 puntos y las preguntas y respuestas son muchisimo mas visibles que los comentarios que van debajo de estas, por lo que encuentro ilogico que se pidan 50 puntos para hacer esto.

Mas que nada lo menciono ya que he visto un par de respuestas y comentarios con errores y me gustaria hacercelos notar a las personas que escribieron estas respuestas y comentarios (para eso entre a este foro, para poder aportar), pero me veo incapacitado para hacerlo.

Comment: dices que se puede contestar y preguntar inmediatamente pero no comentar... Con los comentarios no ganas rep pero si no te dejaran contestar o preguntar ...como ibas a ganar la suficiente para que te dejen? Editando ?

Comment: Mi planteamiento no es hacer que no te dejen preguntar ni responder (ya que entonces la gente nueva no podria hacer nada), si no que mi idea era hacer que te dejen comentar sin la necesidad de tener puntos.

Comment: parece algo basico pero es un privilegio. hay gente que abusa de los comentarios. segun la imoprtancia de cada privilegio, su correspondiente coste en reputacion. Puedes verlos todos en [Privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Creo que 50 puntos es una cifra bastante accesible,  a poco que recibas 5 upvotes los tienes. Y comentar es un privilegio que no debería tener todo el mundo. Hay usuarios que por desconocimiento y simplemente por ineptitud, no hacen buen uso de ello, por eso es necesario un rodaje y un aprendizaje. Considéralo como "el camino del guerrero" :P

Comment: Es normal al principio cuando yo entre pensaba lo mismo, luego te das cuenta de que es cierto que hay gente que abusa de los comentarios. Tambien veras que 50 puntos no es mucho, solo planteate ganarte una reputacion y demostrar que eres confiable en esta comunidad va y te caen 100 punticos en estos dias

Answer (score 6):

A mi en lo personal me parece bien que haya un limite para poder comentar. Esos 50 puntos indican que te tomas en serio el sitio. Comentar es una buena caracteristica del sitio, por lo que si no se regula podras encontrar cada publicacion con muchos comentarios, ya que nuevos usuarios podrian no entender correctamente las mecanicas del sitio, y comentar indiscrimandamente, como si estuvieran chateando. Cuando empece en el sitio me parecio muy molesto no poder comentar, pero lo bueno de esto es que te fija una meta a alcanzar, 50 ptos, lo cual hace que te esfuerces en conseguir reputacion (y asi contribuir mas con el sitio).
Pienso que si no se comportara de esta forma y todos los privilegios estuvieran disponibles desde el principio (sin contar con los de los moderadores), usuarios podrian perder la motivacion de conseguir reputacion y de votar, y se perderia un poco lo que es el sitio.

Comment: El problema es que los downvotes no son visibles hasta que tenga 125 puntos y tampoco les puedo comentar en que se equivocaron...

Osea lo unico que debo hacer por ahora es ignorar...

Comment: Tienes razon :|. Es otra forma de evitar mal comportamiento de nuevos usuarios, supongo. O sea que te quedas con la opcion de reportar (no para cerrar respuestas por estar equivocadas). No obstante, igual, otro objetivo mas a lograr.

Comment: Comentar __es un privilegio__ que se gana participando. Para obtener 50 puntos debes realizar otras actividades como preguntar y responder, por ejemplo. Por cierto, reportar publicaciones también [es un privilegio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: Bueno, pero no creo que dejarle en claro a la persona que realizo una respuesta o un comentario de un error en lo que dijo (en donde la unica forma para hacerlo es a travez de los comentarios) deberia ser un privilegio, ...

Comment: @CodigoFasil -  Si crees que la respuesta es mala o tiene errores... contesta a esa misma pregunta... y si eres mejor en contestar.. tienes en menos de nada los 50 puntos....

Comment: igual cuando la gente publica comentarios como respuestas, los usuarios reportan y/o los moderadores nos damos cuenta y los migramos a su sitio adecuado :D

Comment: @fredyfx lo que nos lleva a una de las razones por las cuales se necesitan esos 50 puntos. la moderacion de los comentarios.

Comment: así es hermano @EmanuelVe :D